# Calculate a total percentage on top of an grouping of a query result in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following table *t*, which is the result of a query:

```
user | value
A    | 1
B    | 2
A    | 1
B    | 4
```

I wish to calculate the following table:

```
user | sum(value) | percentage
A    | 2          | 0.25
B    | 6          | 0.75
```

Getting the percentage is somewhat simple with - thanks @lad2025

```
select sum(value)/(select sum(value) from t) 
from t
group by user
```

The problem is that *t* is already the result of a rather big query, so I'd like to do this without repeating the name of t. Is this possible without creating a view?

Comment: What is the formula you want to use for the percentage? The sum for a user / sum for all?

Comment: Yes, the sum per user / sum for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT `user`, SUM(`value`) AS s,
       SUM(`value`)/(SELECT NULLIF(SUM(value),0) FROM t) AS percentage
FROM t
GROUP BY `user`;
```

Warning! I've assumed that all values are positivie or 0.

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=870c1aa71866e87f1fa6ff5b0f63686d)**

---

*EDIT*:

> The problem is that t is already the result of a rather big query, so I'd like to do this without repeating the name of t.

If you are using MySQL 8.0 or MariaDB you could use `SUM() OVER()`

```
SELECT `user`, SUM(`value`) AS s, SUM(`value`)/SUM(SUM(`value`)) OVER()
FROM t
GROUP BY `user`;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=acdd6c575d5a41dcc5c82e6749ecf072)**

or use CTE:

```
WITH t AS (
   -- super complex query
)
SELECT `user`, SUM(`value`) AS s,
       SUM(`value`)/(SELECT NULLIF(SUM(value),0) FROM t) AS percentage
FROM t
GROUP BY `user`;
```

Comment: Thank you. But I just noticed my need was a bit more complex. I edited the question.

Comment: @NiloAraujo Yes, you could avoid referencing to `t` twice